# Batch process large file split by line endings using FTP streaming in Mule

Tags: java, ftp, mule, batch-processing, mule-component

I'm trying to read in a large file, 100K+ rows, split the file and process the rows. I've set the FTP connector to stream as the file is too large to read into memory but the payload is InputStream which cannot be read into the batch process.

I have a custom java component which converts the `InputStream` to a `String` but I want to be able to return the value in batches (as building the string will ultimately lead to Out of Memory errors anyway) but if I set a counter then the the java component stops reading the `InputStream`.

After this I use a splitter to turn the payload into a `Iterable` object so the batch process can execute.

Is there a way to return the value from the custom java component and continue processing the file to return batches of 500? Or is there a way to make the batch process read `InputStream` datatypes?

I can't find anything online

```xml
<flow name="bulk-flow"> 
    <ftp:inbound-endpoint host="${ftp.host}" port="${ftp.port}" path="${ftp.path}" user="${ftp.user}" password="${ftp.pass}" connector-ref="ftpConnector" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP" pollingFrequency=1000"></ftp:inbound-endpoint>  
    <batch:execute name="batch" doc:name="batch"></batch:execute>  
</flow>
<batch:job name="batch"> 
    <batch:input> 
        <custom-transformer class="InputStreamToString" doc:name="Java"></custom-transformer>  
        <splitter expression="#[payload.split('\n')]" doc:name="Splitter"></splitter>  
    </batch:input>  
    <batch:process-records>
```

and the custom java class

```
public class InputStreamToString extends AbstractMessageTransformer{

@Override
public String transformMessage(final MuleMessage muleMessage, String arg1)
        throws TransformerException {

    String result = "";

    try {
        if (muleMessage.getPayload() != null && muleMessage.getPayload() instanceof InputStream) {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) muleMessage.getPayload();
            result = getStringFromInputStream(is);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new TransformerException(new EscapeUnicodeTransformer(), e);
    }
    return result;
}

// convert InputStream to String
private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;

    String line;
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && count < 500) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            count++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Comment: Yes but you should put the logic in the `Java` portion.  Essentially, have the java break up the batch into sets of 500 per call to the function and have it give output for the function when it finishes 500, then call it again with the next set.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that the next component will not execute until the Java component has finished executing? This would still cause Out of Memory exceptions? I could write another method to run in the finally block to loop through processing all the lines but the Java component will not have finished.

Comment: Well the alternative is to have the Java know nothing about where it is in regards to file index/count.  You'd have to set it up to accept an index argument to tell it where to start (the first 500 files, the second 500, etc) and pass it then let whatever you're using to manage the ftp give this information to your Java program every time it finishes a batch.

Comment: Instead of using batch job, use subflow and call that subflow in java class.

Flow flow = (Flow) objMuleContext.getRegistry().lookupFlowConstruct("Sub_Flow");

MuleEvent inputEvent = new DefaultMuleEvent(objDefaultMuleMessage, MessageExchangePattern.REQUEST_RESPONSE, new DefaultMuleSession());

flow.process(inputEvent);